# Is there a way to filter results in a lookup for certain record types?

Tags: record-type, standard-objects, lookup-filter, criteria-filter

I have a lookup on a custom object to the standard object 'Products'. My custom object has 3 record types, and requires an input from the Products. But I would like to filter which Products are available, per my record types. Is there a way that I can set that up?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Lookup Filter on the lookup field...

[image]